# How to determine the last time a location was visited in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Since items/plants/ore/enemies/etc. respawn following a set number of days after their location was last visited by the player in Skyrim, are there any console commands that can be run to check how long ago a certain location was visited? I've been keeping a small list on a piece of paper, but it sounds like something that might be found with a console command, although I have been unable to find any related commands on [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) or [The Elder Scrolls wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29).

Answer (score 3):

I'm almost positive there are no ways to find out how long. I'm pretty sure the quickest way to regrow plants is just wait (in game) and keep checking on them.

Comment: pretty sure this is the case, unless there's a mod out there (but I doubt it)

Comment: if the respawn is at a set time one could make a mod that adds a "used" tag to plants, ores or locations of items and enemies then have a running timer in the background which pops up some notice saying "it has been X days, maybe i should go check that ore despite at Y to see if there was something i missed" or something along those lines, though it's just a theory, if someone is a modder that's an idea which you can take

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't believe there is a command for what you're asking you could use the timescale command perhaps?

If you're waiting for a particular item/plant etc. to respawn and don't mind about building up your day count you could use:

> set timescale to x

The default for x is 20 so for every minute that passes realtime 20 minutes will pass in Skyrim. If you changed this to 86400 for example you'd have a whole day passing in just a single second.